# Custom WP Comments Query with Nested Comments Possible? (Hierarchy/Depth)

Tags: comments

I've set up a custom WP Comments Query that serves approved comments on posts ordered by date (basic stuff) and everything works fine except the fact that comments are displayed below each other and I'd like them to be nested — like if I was using `wp_list_comments()`.

Is there any template file/function to output comment template to the query so the comment will have a basic wp comment html structure with all the wp classes and reply links?

The reason why I can't use the `wp_list_comments()` is that it doesn't allow to set the `post_id` which I need to set as I'm fetching posts via AJAX, and this function doesn't work properly outside the loop...

Any help/idea is very welcome, thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can pass an array of WP_Comment objects into `wp_list_comments` as second argument.

```
// Query
$comments_query = new WP_Comment_Query;
$comments = $comments_query->query( $args );

// Display
wp_list_comments(array(), $comments);
```

Comment: That works, but I have another question... Who is the best? Wait... I know! You are! Nah, seriously thanks dude I've been looking for this the whole day and this comments is perfect, exactly, what I'm looking for. Fixed all my problems! Many thanks!